# Java8 streams with Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have the following Map (each key is a `String` and each value is a `List<Message>`)

My `map` is like this :

```
1st entry :"MONDAY" -> [message1, message2, message3]
2nd entry : "TUESDAY" -> [message4, message5]
...
```

My goal is to change each message content :

I was thinking about this :

```
map.entrySet().stream().peek(entry -> {
    entry.getValue().stream().peek(m -> m.setMessage(changeMessage()))
})
```

But don't know how to finish and do it properly.

Comment: Haven't tried this yet but was wondering if using simple "forEach" was not better, at least easier.

Comment: `My goal is to change each message content` , means..??give example please.

Comment: Try this `map.forEach((k,v)->v.replaceAll(m->m.setMessage(changeMessage())));` or `map.values().forEach(v->v.replaceAll(m->m.setMessage(changeMessage())));`

Comment: Don’t use `peek` when you mean `forEach`. And don’t use `entrySet()` when you are only interested in the `values()`. Apparently, you just want to do `map.values() .forEach(list -> list.forEach(m -> m.setMessage(changeMessage())));`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) doesn't provide a straightforward way to *change* the `Map` values without violating the [*Side-effects*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) principle:

> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.

Here is a possible solution:

```
Map<String, List<Message>> = map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> {                                                      // iterate entries
            e.setValue(e.getValue().stream()                         // set a new value
                .map(message -> {
                    message  -> message.setMessage(changeMessage()); // .. update message
                    return message;})                                // .. use it
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));                      // return as a List
            return e;})                                              // return an updated value
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));      // collec to a Map
```

However, Java provides a well-known `for-each` feature to achieve your goal in a more direct way which is more readable:

```
for (List<Message> list: map.values()) { 
    for (Message message: list) { 
        message.setMessage(changeMessage()); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate map, change each element of list again put the collected list on the same key of the map.

```
map.forEach((k,v)->{
                map.put(k, v.stream().map(i->i+"-changed").collect(Collectors.toList()));

            });
```

Comment: yeah I was thinking about this : map.forEach((k,v) -> v.forEach(message -> message.setMessage("newValue")});

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the `message` of all messages there is no need to use the whole entry set. You can just stream the values of your map and map the items. The use `forEach()` to update them:

```
map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
        .forEach(m -> m.setMessage(changeMessage(m.getMessage())));
```

If you need the key to change the message you can use this:

```
map.forEach((key, messages) -> messages.forEach(m -> 
        m.setMessage(changeMessage(key, m.getMessage()))));
```